# TypeScript enum from string type conversion error

Tags: angular, typescript

As docs stating, TS supports enums both numeric based and string based:

```
enum numBasedEnum {
  E1 = 0,
  E2 = 1,
}

enum stringBasedEnum {
  E3 = 'Str1'
  E4 = 'Str2'
}
```

Recently my & my team felt into troubles due to issues like:

```
Type '"Str1"' is not assignable to type 'stringBasedEnum'
```

and finally after some casting with quite explicit error:

```
Type 'string' cannot be converted to type 'stringBasedEnum'.
```

Still, for one of us this was working perfectly fine (compilation up & running with no issues) while others fails at compilation time.

We all use npm to keep utilities in same version (clearing cache and re-install all did not help), we are all on Windows based machines and we all uses VS Code as editor.

Any ideas what may cause this problem and how this can be prevented?

I assume this might be some global tools versions (like angular CLI) but isn't project suppose to use local version of tooling while invoking `npm start`?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but I've had more success using the `type` keyword than enums, and it does not depend on owning the same source file (You can't write enums in a d.ts file). An example would be: `type thisOrThat = 'this' | 'that'; var myThis:thisOrThat = 'notthis'; <-- compilation error`. This is sort of the same approach used in native functions like `document.createElement(elementTypeAsString)`

Comment: Your question title is not really a question. Also it's not clear what do you want to solve: problems with enums or "it works on my machine" problem.

Comment: @marzelin preferably both. Anyway, I think that sentence "Any ideas what may cause this problem and how this can be prevented?" confirming that. Title was indeed incorrect

Comment: @Katana314 for string enums this makes sense. As long as number-based enums are a bit different since they can be used nicely in array indexing, for string-based I literally see no difference. Can you please upgrade your comment to answer, I'd like to upvote

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is incorrect. You must use the `enum` keyword before declaring an enum, e.g.

```
enum stringBasedEnum = {
    FOO = 'Foo'
}
```

Comment: Ouh sorry, I wrote this question on phone straight out of head, anyway thanks for hint, I corrected original question. Anyway, this is not an answer, original code is of course prefixed with `enum`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are all compiling with the same version of Typescript.  The string enum feature was added in Typescript 2.4.

Check your global Typescript version with `tsc -v`.

Check your workspace Typescript version use `npx tsc -v`.

Before Typescript 2.4, you could declare enums with string values with hack below.  Use this if you can't update to Typescript 2.4+ yet.

```
enum stringBasedEnum {
    E3 = <any>'Str1'
    E4 = <any>'Str2'
}
```

Also check which version of Typescript that VS code is using.  You can set it to use your global version, the installed VS Code version, or the version installed in your workspace.  Setting this will help the intellisense in VS Code based on the Typescript version you support.

Comment: This is kind of answer I'm looking for. The question in which version of `tsc` is used when `npm run` is invoked?

Comment: The workspace version will be used when running `tsc` from an npm script with `npm run`.

Comment: Then how you would explain that project compiles at my machine while 2 other co-workes have compilation error? Same TSC version shall be used (indeed lower than 2.4.x) but it should fail on my side as well

Comment: Are you generating a package-lock.json file?  Make sure you are and commit that to your source control.  That will make sure everyone installs the same version of your project's packages when they execute `npm install`.

Comment: `package-lock.json` is in place

Comment: Make sure the Typescript version in your `package-lock.json` is 2.4+.

Comment: It's in fact lower than 2.4.+ (2.2.x) and it's the answer why my team mates were not able to compile it. The question remains, why I was able to run  it with no issue?